# Convert phase (angle) to complex value

Tags: c++, eigen

Is there a standard function that does `val = cos(phase) + sin(phas) j`. Is there a conventional name for applying "Euler's formula" to do the opposite of the "[argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/arg)" function? Similar to [`std::polar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/polar), but that expects the magnitude component.

I am looking at a large code base that does the following pattern a lot:

```cpp
Eigen::VectorXf phase = ...;
Eigen::VectorXcf cplx = ...;
cplx.real() = phase.array().cos();
cplx.imag() = phase.array().sin();
```

This unfortunately does not take advantage of `sincos` optimization.

Is there a natural way to do this that I haven't found in the documentation? Is there a conventional name for this?

This is probably what I'm going with, just checking with the world before I change a lot of code.

```cpp
void phase2Cplx(const Eigen::Ref<const Eigen::VectorXf> phaseIn,
        Eigen::Ref<Eigen::VectorXcf> cplxOut) {
    // assert len in == len out
    Eigen::Index len = cplxOut.size();
    std::complex<float> *out = cplxOut.data();
    const float *in = phaseIn.data();
    for (Eigen::Index i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        float val = in[i];
        out[i] = { cosf(val), sinf(val) };
    }
}
// @Details: Using () was measurably worse than []
```

Comment: You may want to search [softwarerecs.se] for some library routines.

Comment: The  `radius, phase` representation is referred to as polar form (hence, presumably the name of `std::polar()`)   The `real, imag` form is referred to as rectangular form, or as the rectangular coordinate form.      So `rectangle()` or `rectangular()` or similar might be candidate names for you to consider.  Conventionally, that would have two arguments (phase and radius) but, in C++ at least, you can specify a default value for radius as `1` or `1.0`.

Comment: `std::polar` and just a plain `std::sin` followed by `std::cos` seemed to be optimised to `sincosf` in gcc, but only in clang with `-ffast-math` https://godbolt.org/z/EWF6zh

Comment: It would probably be even better to store real and imaginary parts as separate vectors. Ideally, sin and cos calculations could be vectorized then, sharing a lot of common code. As of now, this is not possible with Eigen, cf: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=984

Comment: @Peter I'm happy enough to call my function `phaseToRectangular`. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Why doesn’t `[](double t) {return std::polar(1,t);}` (or some equivalent partial application) work?